# Is it worth DIY remove old tiles or just put new tiles on old tiles in Kitchen?

Tags: kitchens, tile

In video removing old tiles does not seem to be that hard. However, can things go wrong when doing so? What type of damage can occur if the tiles does not come off and we apply too much pressure?

Is it really better to just stick new old on top of old ones?

Comment: We need more details here - what type of old tiles?  What type of new tiles?  What type of subfloor are the old tiles on?  How old is the existing floor?

Comment: They are white tiles. I don't know about types. I am just trying to get information before I decide what to do with the kitchen in the house I am buying but not moved into yet.
The kitchen is in ground floor.

Comment: Will there be any clearance issues with drawers or doors if you add a thickness of tile?

Comment: Your questions are impossible to answer without more information. What is the size and composition of the tiles, what is the substrate (floor underneath the tiles) composed of, etc. 
The best answer that anyone can give, in the current state of the question, is "It depends...maybe, maybe not."

Comment: We have to know the basic material of the tiles... Are they ceramic?  Soft peel and stick Vinyl?  More of a hard Vinyl?  Pictures would be good as well.

Comment: How do I find the nature of the tiles and the floor underneath them? I live in UK by the way.

Comment: Upload a picture - that may be enough for us to at least figure out if these are ceramic tiles vs. peel & stick.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends.**

If the current tiles are intact but unfashionable, and if you have enough room above the floor and under the door for new tile, it's easier (read: cheaper) to lay on top. This is usually feasible for most types of actual tile, old and new. Linoleum (not tile), high-gloss tiles (ex subway), and non-ceramic tiles (ex parkay) often don't make suitable underlayment, so they can't be used regardless of the condition they are in.

If the current tiles are broken, missing, crooked, etc, then they need removed for two main reasons: 1. they won't provide a flat stable surface for new tiles. 2. They are probably hiding a sub-floor problem like leaks, joist sagging/warping, rot, insects, mold, etc that should be addressed before doing a new floor anyway.